# from mongodb to array with objects

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

It must be a better way to do this? I want to get all documents from the sounds collection and output them with an **array with objects** in (using it for backbone.js). **It cant be an object with objects in!**

```
$sounds = iterator_to_array($db->sounds->find());

    $a = "[";

    foreach ($sounds as $id => $sound) {
        $a .= json_encode($sound) . ",";
    }

    //remove the last comma...
    $a = substr($a, 0, -1);
    $a .="]";

    echo $a;
```

Comment: How about `echo json_encode(array_values($sounds));` ?

Comment: yea! this works great! could you explain what it does?

Comment: I'll post it as answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
$sounds = iterator_to_array($db->sounds->find());
echo json_encode(array_values($sounds));
```

[`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will return values of associated array as indexed array so [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will return json encoded string in a format you want (i.e. javascript array instead of javascript object).